# select time range using two fields

Tags: elasticsearch

A time range is being defined by `start_date` and `end_date` and I'm trying to get all the documents that a given date, `03/27/2019` in this case, is inside the time range.

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "start_date": {
              "lte": "03/27/2019"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "end_date": {
              "gte": "03/27/2019"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "locations": [
              "all"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": "male"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query does not yield the proper documents, for example a document with the following values:

```
  "start_date": "11/25/2018"
  "end_date": "12/25/2019"
```

Isn't returned

Mapping of fields:

```
"start_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "MM/DD/yyyy"
          },
"end_date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "MM/DD/yyyy"
          },
```

Comment: But the document you get is correct, though. `start_date(11/25/2018) < 03/27/2019 < end_date(12/25/2019)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your date format is wrong.

It should be `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of `MM/DD/yyyy`

Comment: 0 documents are returned with that query

Comment: See my comment above... the returned document is correct according to your expectation, as it is espressed

Comment: so both start_date and end_date should be queried using LTE?

Comment: what I mean is that your query already returns the correct document given what you expect. In my answer I thought you wanted both start/end_date to be on the same date (i.e. 1 one-day interval), so you can forget it.

Comment: I need to get all docs the the given date (03/27/19) is between the doc's start_date and end_date, can you assist?

Comment: That's what your query is already doing, isn't it? You just have a date format issue, it should be `MM/dd/yyyy` not `MM/DD/yyyy`

Comment: thanks, that was the issue (Wrong mapping). Please update your answer so I could accept it.